# How to wrap text in Notepad++, but leave paragraph lines intact?

Tags: merge, notepad++, line

How can I wrap text in Notepad++, but leave paragraph lines intact?

Example:

The original text looks like this:

**This

is

paragraph

one.


This

is

paragraph

two.**

I would like the text to look like this:

**This is paragraph one.


This is paragraph two.**

But currently, when I go to Edit > Blank Operations > Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL, the text ends up with no paragraph line in between, like this:

**This is paragraph one. This is paragraph two.**

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ([^.\s])\r?\n
Replace: $1[ ]
```

### Demo

The regex pattern `([^.\s])\r?\n` will match and capture any letter which appears before a CR?LF character, so long as that character is *not* a full stop.  It then replaces with that same character, followed by just a single space, thereby removing/replacing the original CR?LF.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace every single linebreak with a space.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[^\r\n]+\K\R(?!\R)`
- Replace with:   # a space
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[^\r\n]+        # 1 or more non linebreak
\K              # forget them
\R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!\R)          # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't another linebreak after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]